# nginx-ingress returns 502 After upgrading to kubernetes v1.24.6

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, helm

When trying to upgrade from kubernetes v1.23.X to v1.24.X.
I has been seen that the health probe needs to be changed to be /healthz (azure)

I have a configuration that works in 1.23 but not 1.24
I have a configuration that works in 1.24 but not 1.23

The problem I've got is whilst upgrading to v1.24 nginx-ingress will break introducing down-time.

I've seen some people suggest setting the ports to TCP
[Kubernetes v1.24.3 upgrade broke ingress-nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/1110280/kubernetes-v1-24-3-upgrade-broke-ingress-nginx)

However they have informed us on how to set the healthz probe (great can confirm that works with 1.24) they havn't said how they got the TCP fix to work. I'm hoping that the TCP fix will run in both 1.23 and 1.24

Hopefully one of you can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the following annotation worked:

```
    annotations: 
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path: /healthz
```